# How to find the max number of sales by month using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

i'm having some problems to find the max number of sales by month. 
I have a user which have many orders, each order has a quantity of product (i.e sales). I need to know the maximum value of sales grouped by month but i don't know how to build this on ActiveRecord.

`count(:quantity, :conditions => ['order.user_id = my_user_id], :group => [month])` => it returns a number? or a set of numbers (one for each month)?

If the second answer is true the result could be similar to:

```
orders = Order.maximum.count(:quantity, :conditions => ['order.user_id = my_user_id], :group => [month])
```

I know that this syntax isn't correct, but: Am I on the right way? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: you mean the number of sales on each month, and then get the maximum of this set of values? would these months be from the last year?

Comment: or do you mean to get the sales for each month, and not getting any maximum?

Comment: The first comment is correct @juanpastas. This is what I want. I have to switch the project and I can't solve it yet.

Comment: your answer is incomplete

Comment: I need to get the sales of each month of the last year and after that get the maximum value @juanpastas